# Onclick button Event in fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, buttonclick

I've tried two types of code to get this to work and it keeps giving me force closes when I press the button to go into another Activity. I'm using a Fragment and there's a button in that Fragments code but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidbelieve.activity.LoginActivity;
import com.androidbelieve.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.androidbelieve.helper.SessionManager;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class PrimaryFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView txtName;
private Button btnLogout;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, container, false);

    txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.username);
    btnLogout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.logout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }
    // Fetching user details from SQLite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);


    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }


    });

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saleentry);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

public void updateDetail() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SentFragment.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I was trying to go to another page using button, but it always fail.
**Here is my stacktrace..this is the result when i used onclicklistener**

> 04-07 22:42:37.285 27777-27777/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs >E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs, PID: 27777
>   Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, >com.android.systemui=overlay:system}
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit >activity class >{com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipet>abs.SentFragment}; have you declared this activity in your >AndroidManifest.xml?
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:849)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:907)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:916)
>                                                                                               at com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.PrimaryFragment.updateDetail(PrimaryFragment.java:75)
>                                                                                               at com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.PrimaryFragment$2.onClick(PrimaryFragment.java:67)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5456)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Is SendFragment.class an activity or fragment? You can't use `startActivity` on a fragment.

Comment: fragment@AlexTownsend

Comment: As I said, you can't start a fragment with `startActivity`, only activities. Some options are A) create a new activity that contains your `SendFragment` and start that using `startActivity` or B) replace your `PrimaryFragment` with `SendFragment` on your current activity

Comment: You Should call The Activity of that fragmet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you have to add frame layout in your xml layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

then use this code on click

```
 Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.saleentry);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
           Fragment fragment = new SentFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(new PrimaryFragment ());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
```